# Including ipynb files in sphinx index.rst when they are located in a subdirectory

Tags: python, directory, python-sphinx, subdirectory

I am stuck with pythons `sphinx`. My directory tree looks like this:

```
| - project_root
|    | - importable_project
|    |    | - importable_module.py
|    |    | - another_importable_module.py
|    |    | - Tutorials
|    |    |    | - tutorial1.ipynb
|    | - docs
|    |    | - build
|    |    |    | - sphinx_build_files_and_folders
|    |    | - source
|    |    |    | - _static
|    |    |    | - _templates
|    |    |    | - conf.py
|    |    |    | - index.rst
|    |    |    | - modules.rst
```

I have enabled the [nbsphinx extention](http://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.1/pre-executed.html) as per the instructions and I'm modifying the `index.rst` file within the source folder.

Here is what the `index.rst` file currently looks like:

```
.. Pycotools documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Wed Oct 11 11:46:06 2017.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Pycotools's documentation!
=====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   /modules
   ../../importable_project/Tutorials/tutorial1


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Most of this was automatically generated by `sphinx-quickstart`. I understand that file paths specified here are relative to the location of the `index.rst` file. So in this case `project_root/docs/source` and sphinx is able to generate html for  `moudles.rst` with the `index.rst` file above.

The problem is that I would like to include my tutorials in the documentation but the line `../../importable_project/Tutorials/tutorial1` is not able to locate `tutorial1.ipynb`.

Can anybody suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Tutorials are documentation, and should be moved into the `docs/source` directory. Sphinx cannot find files outside of its source directory, except for packages via autodoc. You'll need to adjust your path accordingly after moving the `.ipynb` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tutorials are documentation, and should be moved into the `docs/source` directory. Sphinx cannot find files outside of its source directory, except for packages via autodoc. You'll need to adjust your path accordingly after moving the `.ipynb` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nbsphinx-link](https://nbsphinx-link.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

On an easier structure:

```
|Project root
     |notebooks
           |sample.ipynb
     |docs
          |build
          |source
```

Install nbsphinx-link

```
pip install nbsphinx-link
```

add both nbsphinx and nbsphinx_link as extensions in your Sphinx build config, typicalyl in conf.py:

```
    extensions = [
       # ...
       # any other extensions you need,
       # ...
       'nbsphinx',
       'nbsphinx_link',
    ]
```

Add a .nblink file in source dir linking to your notebook.

```
    |Project root
     |notebooks
           |sample.ipynb
     |docs
          |build
          |source
               |sample.nblink
```

Add the path to the notebook in sample.nblink

```
{
"path": "relative/path/to/notebook"
}
```

Link .nblink file in your index.rst then should work